# Django channels 2 async retrieve and save data to database

Tags: python, django-channels

I'm trying to asynchronously get object from the database, update it, and then save it with Django Channels 2. The retrieval works, but I'm having problems with the saving.

I already tried with

```py
await database_sync_to_async(game.save)()
```

as well as moving the actual saving in another method, like this

```py
@database_sync_to_async
def save(self, item):
    item.save()
```

```py
class GameController(AsyncWebsocketConsumer):
    @property
    @database_sync_to_async
    def game(self):
        return Game.objects.get(uuid=self.game_uuid)

    async def save_connected(self):
        game = await self.game
        if not game.data:
            game.data = {
                'connected': False
            }
        else:
            game.data['connected'] = True
        await database_sync_to_async(game.save)()
```

But I always get this error: `Object of type coroutine is not JSON serializable`
or the data is not saved at all.

Comment: Stacktrace? This error likely occurs where you're are calling self.send_json so please include more code

Comment: I'm not calling self.send_json anywhere. The stacktrace points to `await database_sync_to_async(game.save)()`

Comment: The `database_sync_to_async` at the point of calling the method is unnecessary since the method is already wrapped with it